# Dynamically call textboxfor with reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, html-helper

The end result of what I am trying to do is build a form dynamically by reflecting an object and it's properties.

I've created HtmlHelper methods that call TextBoxFor and CheckBoxFor and so on, but now I need help figuring out how to properly reflect the property when passing it to Html.TextBoxFor

Here's the helper method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FormTextBox<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, String id, String property_name, object model, RouteValueDictionary attributes)
    {          
        Type model_type = model.GetType();

        return helper.TextBoxFor(model_object => model_type.InvokeMember(property_name, BindingFlags.ExactBinding | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, model, null));
    }
```

But it breaks on the return with this error code:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Basically I want to take what would be this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```

And turn it into this:

```
@FormHelpers.FormTextBox("Name", model)
```

And have it output the same thing.

**UPDATE**

I will restate this, as I have made some progress in solving the problem.

I've created an Expression from Expression.PropertyOrField that creates exactly what I am looking for. However I can't get the TextBoxFor function to accept it.

```
Expression fieldExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(model),property_name);

        return helper.TextBoxFor(Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel>>(fieldExpr, null).Compile()());
```

Any ides on how to properly pass the Expression to the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem by building a lambda expression using the property name and the type of the object being passed in using the library `System.Linq.Expressions`.

```
ParameterExpression fieldName = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), property_name);
Expression fieldExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(model), property_name);
Expression<Func<TModel, object>> exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, object>>(fieldExpr, fieldName);

return helper.TextBoxFor(exp);
```

Example:

```
@{ Name myname = new Name();}
@Html.FormTextBox("first", myname)
```

fieldName builds an expression for the left hand side (first) and then fieldExpr builds the body of the expression with the class name and property name.

exp ends up looking like this:

```
first => value(DynamicForm.Models.Name).first
```

Comment: Data annotations still work!

And since moving forward on this project I've also created helpers that add validation for these fields automagically. Pretty useful set of helpers for creating data driven forms in mvc with validation.

Comment: This will not work for `int`, `DateTime` and possibly other types. `Expression of type '' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'`

Comment: @FlorinSecal, just change the Object in the `Func<TModel, Object>` with the type you need.

Comment: @Azura thanks. I've added a switch on the object type to keep it "dynamic"

Comment: For me, this worked at treat! For anyone else like me who had to quickly look it up - the Expression classes live inside of 'using System.Linq.Expressions.'

Answer (score 0):

To get a property using reflection, use code like this:

```
var prop = model_type.GetProperty(property_name);
//then in your loop:
prop.GetValue(model, null)
```

Or if you're only going to get the property from one object, make it one line:

```
model_type.GetProperty(property_name).GetValue(model, null);
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same error. Doesn't this just get the value which would be a string?

I want the whole property to go along so that it properly data binds and I get it when the action is called when submitting the form.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TextBoxFor, but GetProperty returns a PropertyInfo object.  Maybe you can give it that?  Or maybe you need to be looking at setting a binding.

Comment: Right, I understand that GetProperty returns a PropertyInfo object, that's why in my example I used InvokeMember.