# How to POST complex models to action using reflection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to gain a better understanding and knowledge of MCV4.

Whats the best way to pass the property CategoryType of my Product object back to the controller on a HttpPost.

I am looking for an approach so I don't have to write out every property by hand.
I am currently using reflection to iterate over the properties of the Category type and add them as hidden input variables using the @Html.Hidden method.
This works but I want to know if I am doing it the right way (best practices).

1. I would like to know how to achieve what I have done below using @Html.HiddenFor method. I can't figure out how to write lambda expressions with property information from reflection.
2. Is there a better way to deal with passing the Category object to my controller. My view is strongly typed. Should it know to pass back the Product object on a post.

I have a complex type as follows.

```
    public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public Category CategoryType { get; set; }
}


public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

With a Controller as follows

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Product/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        //Add a new product to the cheese category.
        var product = new Product();
        var category = new Category { Id = 1, CategoryName = "Cheese" };
        product.CategoryType = category;

        return View(product);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Add to repository code goes here

            //Redirect to Index Page
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

And with the Add view of

```
    @model BootstrapPrototype.Models.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}

<h2>Add</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductName);
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductName);

    foreach(var property in Model.CategoryType.GetType().GetProperties())
    {

        //I know how to use the Hidden but would also know how to use the HiddenFor with reflections.
        @Html.Hidden("CategoryType." + property.Name, property.GetValue(Model.CategoryType));
    }

    <button type="submit">Add</button>

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why Hidden?

I think the reason why you are putting the category fields in a hidden field is because you do not want users to updated them, but also you need those values back as part of your `Product` object, or else your product object will get saved without a category (with `null` value). This is exactly the reason why `ViewModel`s are very important. You create a viewmodel that accepts input of those values that you only need. So if you need to create the a product where you only need the name, and with a pre-selected-non-editable category, then you can have a viewmodel:

```
public class ProductModel {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public strnig Name{get;set;}
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
}
```

and a view

```
@model ProductModel 
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.CategoryId)
@Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.Name)
```

that you can get from a controller method

```
public ActionResult Add() {
    var product = new ProductModel {
        CategoryId = getIdFromDb("cheese");
    };
    return View();
}
```

that you can receive in a controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(ProductMOdel input) {
    // map input to an entity
    var productENtity = mapModelToEntity(input);
    // save entity to your repo
}
```

This advantage of this approach can be magnified if you have a hundred fields in your `Product` and `Category` classes. And that you have a use case where only part of those fields will be edited.

### Scaffolding

But of course you can still do it your way. But instead of doing reflection that gives an overhead you should instead get rid of that and do scaffolding. In that manner, you don't have to hand-code all the fields of your classes. Here are two good links that will get you started with Scaffolding:

- [EF Code First and Data Scaffolding with the ASP.NET MVC 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx)
- [MvcScaffolding: One-to-Many Relationships](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/)

### Using Reflection

But if you insist on using reflection then it's totally possible (you almost had it in your code)

```
@foreach(var property in Model.CategoryType.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    @Html.Hidden("Product." + property.Name, 
        property.GetValue(Model.CategoryType));
}
```

The key to that code is `"Product."` that allows the model binder do it's job - the values in the hidden field will be passed back to your POST controller method. However, if the `CategoryType` is null, that code will NOT work.

Comment: The reason for the hidden CategoryId is that they have already selected their Category in a previous View. For example they are already view all "Cheeses" and they with to add a new "Cheese".

Comment: That's understandable, I even had a hidden field in my example. But what about for your other fields? You don't need to pass them around unnecessarily right.

Comment: The reason for the hidden CategoryId is that they have already selected their Category in a previous View. For example they are already view all "Cheeses" and they with to add a new "Cheese". 

I have been using the http://nuget.org/packages/twitter.bootstrap.mvc4 package which is where all the reflection and auto scaffolding was coming from.

I will check out the Scaffolding to see how it works.

I am now only dealing with the CategoryId and not the whole category object within my ViewModel.

Comment: You are right I don't need to pass them around unnecessarily. This answers part 2 of my questions.

Comment: Part 1 of the questions is more of an academic question of is it possible. Can I use reflection on my model in a lambda expression to access a property.

Comment: "Can I use reflection on my model in a lambda expression to access a property" - definitely yes, there's nothing stopping you from doing that. Is it best practice though, I don't think so.

Comment: How do I achieve this. I have tried @Html.HiddenFor(m => property.GetValue(m.CategoryType)); but it returns "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.".

Comment: `Html.Hidden` is enough, see my updated answer, your almost nailed it in your code (in your question).

Comment: Sorry for dragging this out but I know how to achieve the result using Html.Hidden. I was just trying to figure out if it was possible to use Html.HiddenFor using and expression with reflection. If so how can you do it.

Comment: I don't know how `HiddenFor` works internally (would be good to have a peek on the source code). BUT, the reason it will not work is because hiddenfor expects an **object property** not an **object value**. PropertyInfo.GetValue returns an "object value" and that's why it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I found someone else that had the same questions for using textboxfor with reflection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208911/dynamically-call-textboxfor-with-reflection. As you said not best practice but at least I know it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe MVC4 has [HiddenInputAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.hiddeninputattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). You can use that in combination with Html.EditorFor.